# Print out 2 graphs in python

Tags: python

Im a beginner when it comes to python OOP so i ask for some help regarding some small stuff.

Firstly before we are required to print out the results we are asked to calculate different stuff for example one of them is from Class BSC the value of Snr_BSC(Its just formulas)

What i dont understand though for this first part we are required to print out the result first then we transform it into DB(a premade function given to us by professors)
BUt what i dont get is when i go to print out the result it gives one single value.

THe `error_probability` given in the `exercise1()` function is not just one value so why is it printing out just one

```
class BSC():
    def __init__(self,error_probability):
        self.error_probability=error_probability

    @property
    def snr_BSC(self):  #interested in this one here which is found with the formula below
        error_probability=self.error_probability
        snr_lin_BSC=1/(4*error_probability)
        return snr_lin_BSC

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin_BSC = self.snr_BSC
        snr_db = lin2db(snr_lin_BSC)
        return snr_db
```

Secondly we are required to print out two graphs separetely in `exercise1` but i dont know how to do that

```
def exercise1():
    fs_step = 2.75625e3
    error_probability = np.arange(start=1e-12, stop=1)
    n_bit = np.array([2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], dtype=np.int64)
    adc=ADC(n_bit)
    bsc=BSC(error_probability)
    print('Quantization SNR',adc.snr)
    plt.plot(n_bit,adc.snr_db) #first funct i want to print
    plt.xlabel('n_bit')
    plt.ylabel('SNR in db')
    print('Quantization SNR_BSC', bsc.snr_BSC)
    plt.xlabel('P_e')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.plot(error_probability,bsc.snr_db) #Secondfunct i want to print

    plt.ylabel('SNR in db')
    plt.show()
```

For those that need to see the whole project

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcol

color_dict = mcol.TABLEAU_COLORS


def lin2db(x):
    return 10*np.log10(x)


def db2lin(x):
    return 10**(x/10)

class ADC():

    def __init__(self,n_bit):
        self.n_bit=n_bit

    @property
    def snr(self):
        n_bit=self.n_bit
        M=2**n_bit
        snr_lin=M**2
        return snr_lin

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin=self.snr
        snr_db=lin2db(snr_lin)
        return snr_db

    @property
    def m(self):
        M=2**n_bit
        return M

class BSC():
    def __init__(self,error_probability):
        self.error_probability=error_probability

    @property
    def snr_BSC(self):
        error_probability=self.error_probability
        snr_lin_BSC=1/(4*error_probability)
        return snr_lin_BSC

    @property
    def snr_db(self):
        snr_lin_BSC = self.snr_BSC
        snr_db = lin2db(snr_lin_BSC)
        return snr_db


def exercise1():
    fs_step = 2.75625e3
    error_probability = np.arange(start=1e-12, stop=1)
    n_bit = np.array([2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16], dtype=np.int64)
    adc=ADC(n_bit)
    bsc=BSC(error_probability)
    print('Quantization SNR',adc.snr)
    plt.plot(n_bit,adc.snr_db)
    plt.xlabel('n_bit')
    plt.ylabel('SNR in db')
    print('Quantization SNR_BSC', bsc.snr_BSC)
    plt.xlabel('P_e')
    plt.xscale('log')
    plt.plot(error_probability,bsc.snr_db)

    plt.ylabel('SNR in db')
    plt.show()

exercise1()
```

Comment: You forgot to define `ADC`

Comment: @mozway Everything works i just didnt post the whole thing. Just the parts i had questions about. Do i need to upload everything? The rest works

Comment: You said "THe error probability given in the exercise1() function is not one value", which leads me to believe you have not actually printed it to check, because it definitely IS one value.

Comment: @TimRoberts i havent yes. Then how do i define it. It is for example from 1e-12 to 1. I thought the ```np.arange``` did the range thing

Comment: If you plot `plt.plot(error_probability,bsc.snr_db, marker='o')` you'll see your point

Comment: @mozway As somebody above mentioned ```error_probability``` is a point but its not supposed to be. It is required to be between 1e-12 and 1. I thought that ```np.arange``` would do that but apparently i was mistaken. How can i set a range for such a small number?

Comment: I see, then you should use `np.linspace(start=1e-12, stop=1)`

Comment: Or actually rather `np.logspace(start=-12, stop=0)` as you're using a log scale

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592. Before posting a question here, look for the apparent cause of the problem by carefully checking what the code is doing, step by step, and verifying the values in variables at various points in the process. If you have isolated a specific cause for a problem and don't understand why that specific part does something different from what you expect, and you can't find an existing duplicate question, then post the corresponding MRE.